# Aligning form fields in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to align a few forms fields using Bootstrap, so that they display nicely on the page.

Here is a simple form as an example, with accompanying [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vtuc2zc/):

```
<div>
  <select size="5">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value=""> True/False
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="description" class="col-sm-4">Description</label>
  <input type="text" id="description" name="description">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="notes" class="col-sm-4">Notes</label>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="notes" id="notes">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `select` field and the `checkbox` field are not in-line with the `input` and `textarea` fields.

How can I make everything line up nicely?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrap [forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). For example: `.form-horizontal`.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" size="5">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> True/False
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="notes" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Notes</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Khalid's answer is the correct approach, sometimes you might also get that problem with bootstrap's forms. Simplest approach is to use `< br >` after label tag:

```
  <label for="notes" class="col-sm-4">Notes</label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="notes" id="notes">
  </textarea>
```

It's not the best - i should mention it again- if you want to be called a 2017 HTML programer. But maybe it's not that serious.